# About the upper bound of the multiplicity of a divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

It maybe an elementary question. Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $D$ an effective divisor on $X$. My question is the following:

> Can we say that $\mathrm{sup}_x\mathrm{mult}_xD<\infty$, where $x\in X$ is running through the closed points of $X$?

My approach is the following: Let $f:X'\to X$ be a blowup of $X$ along a closed point $x\in X$. Let $a:=\mathrm{mult}_xD$. Suppose $H$ is an ample divisor on $X'$ Then $f^*D-aE$ is effective, and hence we have $(f^*D-aE)\cdot H^{\dim X-1}\ge 0$. It means that
$$ a\le \frac{f^*D\cdot H^{\dim X-1}}{E\cdot H^{\dim X-1}}\le f^*D\cdot H^{\dim X-1}.$$
The upper bound seems independent of $x$. What is the next step? Or, is there an easy counterexample?

Comment: What you wrote is fine. You could as well take a hypersurface $H$ in $X$ transversal to $D$ at $x$, so that $\operatorname{mult}_X(D)\leq D\cdot H $.